# 2 columns, A and B, Col A is T/F, Col B is a non-negative float, and I want to know the first cell (or row) where A = T and B = 0

Tags: excel-formula

I need an Excel formula for this problem (I would rather not use VBA):

I have 2 adjacent columns (call them A and B), Col A is T/F while Col B is a non-negative float, and I want to know the first cell where A = T and B = 0

```
A  B
-----
T 10    
T 11    
F 0    
T 13    
T 0   [5] (stop here because this is the first row where A=T and B=0

A  B
-----
T 10    
T 11    
T 0   [3] (stop here because this is the first row where A=T and B=0
```

I am thinking the answer is going to involve array formulas, and it will involve converting T/F into a binary array (0,1) as well as the floating point array, then ANDing them to find the first 1.  This would be easier in VBA but I'm hoping there is an Excel formula based appraoch

The first row where A=T and B=0

Comment: what do you mean by `stop` are you trying to set that as the bottom of a range?  If so where does the range start and what are you going to do with that range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is the row:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(A1:A100)/((A1:A100="T")*(B1:B100=0)),1)
```

[image]